# how to sendkeys to an authentication popupon firefox 38.5.2

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, firefoxdriver, waits

[image: image of the issue]

Hello all,
i'm trying to automate a webpage scenario with a pop up on firefox 38.5.2 using java. however i haver this error =>  **Action error encountered result: false message: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for page load.**
this is due to the webpage loading continuously even when the pop-up appear causing java to never go to the next line code.
if i do this on a recent browser the webpage doesn't load continously.
i must absolutely use firefox 38.5.2.
if someone has an idea thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include the code you are using? There isn't enough information to help you without seeing your code.